# Regular Expression to search and replace in notepad ++

Tags: regex, notepad++

If i have a line of text that i want to remove from a text file in notepad and it is always formatted like this

[text]:

except that the words in the text area change. what is a regular expression i could create to remove the whole section with the search and replace function in notepad?

Comment: Exactly what can be inside the square brackets? Upper case? Lower case? digits? spaces? tabs? punctuation?

Comment: @alph you mean this http://regex101.com/r/kF4pU2/8 ?

Answer (score 1):

To delete the entire line starting with `[`*any text*`]:` you can use: `^[\t ]*\[.*?\]:.*?\r\n`

Explanation:

`^` ... start search at beginning of a line (in this case).

`[\t ]*` ... find 0 or more tabs or spaces.

`\[` ... find the opening square bracket as literal character.

`.*?` ... find 0 or more characters except the new line characters carriage return and line-feed non greedy which means as less characters as possible to get a positive match, i.e. stop matching on first occurrence of following `]` in the search expression.

`\]:` ... find the closing square bracket as literal character and a colon.

`.*?\r\n` ... find 0 or more characters except the new line characters and finally also the carriage return and line-feed terminating the line.

The search string `^[\t ]*\[.*?\]:.*?$` would find also the complete line, but without matching also the line termination.

The replace string is for both search strings an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

If by removing the entire section, you mean remove the [text]: up to the next [otherText]:, you can try this:

```
\[text\]:((?!\[[^\]]*\]:).)*
```

Remember to set the flag for ". matches newline".

This regex basically first matches your section title. Then, it would start matching right after this title and for each character, it uses a negative lookahead to check if the string following this character looks like a section title. If it does the matching is terminated.

Note: Remember that this regex would replace all occurrences of the matched pattern. In other words, if you have more than one of that section, they are both replaced.